# Floating action button (FAB) above a ListView in a Fragment in xml?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I used code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731721/how-do-you-put-a-floating-action-button-fab-above-a-listview-in-a-fragment-in/36966433#36966433).
In my case it looks like

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.FragmentList"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear">

    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    fab:elevation="6dp"
    fab:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    fab:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/listView"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But i have "multiple root tags" in Android Studio. What i did wrong?
Please help me, i cant understand ((

Comment: put everything inside coordinator layout

Comment: Thanks! Why android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" does not work? FAB is on left and top

Answer (score 3):

Use this layout instead:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.FragmentList"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linear">

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    fab:elevation="6dp"
    fab:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    fab:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/listView"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:fitSystemWindow="true"` to `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

change this line of code 
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
to
     android:layout_gravity="top"

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

This will set the FAB to bottom right.